# Prolog: how to get all the combinations

Tags: prolog, combinations

I have the following for example:

```
bag(b1)
bag(b2)

item(i1)
item(i2)
item(i3)
item(i4)
```

Now i don't really understand how i can get all possibilities out of this? I must use all bags.
Like i should get a list of lists like this:

`[
[together(b1, [i1,i2,i3,i4]), together(b2, [])]
,..., 
[together(b1, [i1]), together(b2, [i2,i3,i4])]
[together(b1, [i1,i2]), together(b2, [i3,i4])]
]`

etc all possible combinations **but it must use all items**. I know i can get the facts using `findall`, but then i'm stuck

this is what i have:

```
test(X) :-
findall(C, bag(C),Bags),
findall(K, item(K),Items),
something???
```

Any ideas on where to start because i'm clueless and i don't understand how to think to achieve such results.

**Possible idea to get the combination:**

```
item_combination(C) :-
    findall(I, item(I), Is),
    combination(Is, C).

combination(_, []).
combination(Set, [X|Xs]) :-
    select(X, Set, Set0),
    combination(Set0, Xs).
```

I would need something like, get a combinations of the first bag and then, go to the next bag, take a combination, and if it's valid (all items used) append to the list, else go back to the first bag with another combination and so on... or are there better solutions ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first define a predicate `powset/3` that generates all powersets out of a given set and the *not-selected elements* as third list:

```
powset3([],[],[]).
powset3([H|T],T2,[H|T3]) :-
    powset3(T,T2,T3).
powset3([H|T],[H|T2],T3) :-
    powset3(T,T2,T3).
```

Next, we define a `divide/3` command that given a list of items, divides it over `N` sets:

```
divide(_,N,[]) :-
    N < 1.
divide(Items,1,[Items]).
divide(Items,N,[Selected|Other]) :-
    N > 1,
    powset3(Items,Selected,Rest),
    N1 is N-1,
    divide(Rest,N1,Other).
```

And finally a `ziptogether/3` utility, that zips two lists into a list of predicates:

```
ziptogether([],[],[]).
ziptogether([HA|TA],[HB|TB],[together(HA,HB)|TC]) :-
    ziptogether(TA,TB,TC).
```

You can do this with:

```
findall(I,item(I),Is),
findall(B,bag(B),Bs),
length(Bs,NB),
findall(Proposal,(divide(Is,NB,Ds),ziptogether(Bs,Ds,Proposal)),List).
```

**Example:**

```
?- findall(I,item(I),Is),
|        findall(B,bag(B),Bs),
|        length(Bs,NB),
|        findall(Proposal,(divide(Is,NB,Ds),ziptogether(Bs,Ds,Proposal)),List).
Is = [i1, i2, i3, i4],
Bs = [b1, b2],
NB = 2,
List = [[together(b1, []), together(b2, [i1, i2, i3, i4])], [together(b1, [i4]), together(b2, [i1, i2, i3])], [together(b1, [i3]), together(b2, [i1, i2, i4])], [together(b1, [i3, i4]), together(b2, [i1, i2])], [together(b1, [i2]), together(b2, [i1|...])], [together(b1, [i2|...]), together(b2, [...|...])], [together(b1, [...|...]), together(..., ...)], [together(..., ...)|...], [...|...]|...].
```

**Lazy version**:

The previous version using `findall` is *active*: it generates the entire list of configurations. In many cases lazy evaluation is better: it enables one to generate a limited number of instance. The lazy version is:

```
getBagConfig(Proposal) :-
    findall(I,item(I),Is),
    findall(B,bag(B),Bs),
    length(Bs,NB),
    divide(Is,NB,Ds),
    ziptogether(Bs,Ds,Proposal).
```

---

**Time complexity:** *the algorithm runs in O(b^n+b+n) with b the number of bins and n the number of bins and n the number of items.*

**Note:** *it is very likely some of the introduced predicates already exist in a lot of Prolog implementations, but since these predicates are not standardized, it is better to provide an implementation oneself.*

Comment: New version using powersets, is this the intended program?

Comment: Haa, no, you probably want to devide the items over the three bags, like the 0-1 multiknapsack problem?

Comment: Yes, it must use all items, (i gave an example of a solution in the question) and yes something like the knapsack problem, but i just don't get it how you have to think to solve it :)

Comment: That seems to be correct.. :) I'll check it out, thanks